# RDP through SSH tunnel fails

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, rdp, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up RDP through SSH tunneling to an Amazon EC2 instance, but it is failing.  I have set up PuTTY properly and can connect to the remote server via RDP and log in, but after successful log in I get a blank screen and then get a timeout error. Looking through the terminal services event viewer  on the remote machine, I get a "session reconnection succeeded" with the source IP the same as the remote machine (i.e., through the tunnel) but about a minute later I get a "session disconnected" event with no errors.  What could be causing the problem and how can I debug it?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: My I ask why you're doing this? The RDP protocol already uses SSL.

Comment: @Ryan Ries To get through our proxy. :(  If there's a better suggestion, please let me know but this is what the last people who worked on it came up with.

Comment: Why not use TSGateway? That should get you through your proxy as it uses TCP 443

Comment: @DKNUCKLES Thanks for the tip... I will investigate that option, but the short answer is that there are more than a couple institutional roadblocks.

Comment: @RyanRies: usually people tunnel through ssh when native ports aren't accessible because they are blocked at a firewall somewhere

Comment: Can you give us your putty config? with the IP addrs masked if necessary?

Comment: Or try setting up a load balancer to one of your servers that listens on tcp 443 and Instance port tcp 3389. Worked for me....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about circumventing IT policy (your organization's proxy).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have port 3389 available to you because of firewall restrictions, then I'd say your options are to either install Remote Desktop Gateway (formally Terminal Services Gateway) on the computer, which is an RPC over HTTP proxy to get remote desktop connections over port 443 (with the added bonus of being able to forward the RDP traffic to another machine beyond the gateway, which you don't need for this specific problem, but that's what the gateway is for.)

Or, a simpler approach would be to simply change the listening port of the Remote Desktop server.

From [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759):

> 1. Start Registry Editor.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber`
> 3. On the Edit menu, click Modify, and then click Decimal.
> 4. Type the new port number, and then click OK. (Such as 443)
> 5. Quit Registry Editor.
> 6. Restart the computer.

Then type `myserver.inthecloud.com:443` to connect from your client.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm intrigued by just using port 443, but can I set up my RDP client to use our SOCKS proxy to connect to myserver:443?